# Fetching data from mysql using php return no result

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to output the data from mysql, a very simple and fundamental thing to do, but the output is blank although the database contains the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbVEh.png)

```
require 'dbHandler.inc.php';
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cityName']);
$rowReturned = array();
print_r($_POST);
$sqlText = "SELECT * FROM batdongsan WHERE city =? ";
echo $sqlText;
echo $city;

if($sqlStatement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sqlText)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sqlStatement, "s", $city);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sqlStatement);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sqlStatement);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "Tran Duy Hung";
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($sqlStatement);
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Output is here:

```
successfully connect to the db
Array ( [cityName] => Hà Nội [address] => [minPrice] => [maxPrice] => [searchSubmit] => )
SELECT * FROM batdongsan WHERE city =? Hà Nội
```

Comment: Do you reach inside of `if` statement? Do you get correct output when doing manual query `SELECT * FROM batdongsan WHERE city ="Hà Nội"`? Try first city without non-latin letters

Comment: since you're using parameterised queries, you do not need to use  mysqli_real_escape_string(). In fact it is potentially corrupting your input data. The bind_param() method will escape the parameter data automatically, so effectively what you're doing here is double-escaping. This could be one reason the query doesn't match. Another could be to do with the encoding of UTF-8 characters - it's not clear what encoding method you've set in the database, or in your PHP connection object.

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: If you do not see `Tran Duy Hung` in the output, then the code is not getting into the WHILE Loop. If it is not getting into the WHILE Loop, it means there is nothing in the resultset. If there is nothing in the resultset, then the query either failed, or found nothing. So @ADyson is almost definitely correct. You have corrupted the `cityName` by unnecessarily escaping it

Comment: One thing to check, did you set the charset for the connection? See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: And this also may be worth a quick read [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) specially the bit about `taking into account the current charset of the connection`

Comment: Calling `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` before executing your statement should be the solution because you have non ASCII chars in your city field

Comment: Thanks for helping guys! I forgot to set the charset and the solution is $conn->set_charset(utf8) where $conn is connection to database.

Answer (score 0):

right after this....

```
require 'dbHandler.inc.php';
```

put, this or put it right after your mysqli_real_connect() or mysqli_connect() call...

```
        @mysqli_query ( $conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';");
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the help! what i do is to use set_charset(utf8) and it works